# Show child custom post types list inside single parent custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have 3 custom post types called country, producer and wine. I want to show producers list inside single country, then show wines list inside single producer. Admin will create country , producer and wine later, so i am not sure if taxonomy will help. Cause while displaying child post types i will need to query through parent post and filter them using category taxonomy, which is not possible unless categories are predefined. Can i do it using taxonomy? or is there any other more dynamic solution? I am new on WordPress so please help me with details. Many thanks